# Ctrl + k ctrl + f not working properly on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I select a piece of code in an HTML page on vscode:

[image: code to format]

And then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

I don't obtain the desired formatted code, I obtain this:

[image: wrongly formatted code]

Does anyone have the same problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the desired formatter for this purpose.
You can use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

And configure settings to work according to your need

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem.